# Can't predict new data after training RFE and model in a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, predict, rfe

I'm brand new to Python and machine learning and I'm surely missing something.

I'm training a RandomForest model through nested CV for hyperparameter tuning and RFECV using a pipeline. I retrieved best_estimator_.n_features and it stills shows me the 17 original features before RFECV narrowing down to 3.

```
X
1182 rows × 17 columns

cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs=-1, criterion='entropy', bootstrap=False)
space = {'n_estimators':  [900, 1000, 1100],
         'max_depth': [25, 50, 100],
         'min_samples_split': [500, 750, 1000],
         'min_samples_leaf': [32, 64]
        }
      
search = GridSearchCV(clf, space, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=1, cv=cv_inner, refit=True)
rfe = RFECV(estimator=RandomForestClassifier())
ppln = Pipeline(steps=[('rfe',rfe),('grid',search)])
cv_outer = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
scores = cross_val_score(ppln, X, y.ravel(), scoring='accuracy', cv=cv_outer, n_jobs=-1)
ppln.fit(X, y.ravel())
```

After I fitted pipeline I tried to predict a new data (fixt) with original 17 features. However the error message shown was: "ValueError:  Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 17 and input n_features is 3."

```
fixtureXLS = pd.read_excel('aaafixtures.xlsx')
fixtureXLS.to_csv('bbbfixtures.csv', encoding='utf-8')
fixt = pd.read_csv('bbbfixtures.csv')
fixt = fixt.loc[:, ~fixt.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
if 'Result' in fixt.columns:
fixt = fixt.drop(['Result'], axis=1)

fixt
287 rows × 17 columns
fixt['Predicted'] = ppln.predict(fixt)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-e54f4c6f6e05> in <module>
----> 1 temp = ppln.predict(fixt)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    117 
    118         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 119         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    120         # update the docstring of the returned function
    121         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    406         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
    407             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
--> 408         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    409 
    410     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='_final_estimator')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    117 
    118         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 119         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    120         # update the docstring of the returned function
    121         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in predict(self, X)
    485         """
    486         self._check_is_fitted('predict')
--> 487         return self.best_estimator_.predict(X)
    488 
    489     @if_delegate_has_method(delegate=('best_estimator_', 'estimator'))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict(self, X)
    627             The predicted classes.
    628         """
--> 629         proba = self.predict_proba(X)
    630 
    631         if self.n_outputs_ == 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    671         check_is_fitted(self)
    672         # Check data
--> 673         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
    674 
    675         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X)
    419         check_is_fitted(self)
    420 
--> 421         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
    422 
    423     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    394         n_features = X.shape[1]
    395         if self.n_features_ != n_features:
--> 396             raise ValueError("Number of features of the model must "
    397                              "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
    398                              "input n_features is %s "

ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 17 and input n_features is 3
```

I transformed fixt to 3 features and predicted pipeline:

```
X_new = rfe.transform(fixt)
print(X_new.shape[1])
fixt['Predicted'] = ppln.predict(X_new)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-02280f45be5a> in <module>
----> 1 fixt['Predicted'] = ppln.predict(X_new)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    117 
    118         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 119         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    120         # update the docstring of the returned function
    121         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    405         Xt = X
    406         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 407             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    408         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    409 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\_base.py in transform(self, X)
     82             return np.empty(0).reshape((X.shape[0], 0))
     83         if len(mask) != X.shape[1]:
---> 84             raise ValueError("X has a different shape than during fitting.")
     85         return X[:, safe_mask(X, mask)]
     86 

ValueError: X has a different shape than during fitting.
```

Can you help me sending some light, please?!

Comment: Please include the full backtrace, so it is easier to identify the issue.

Comment: Hey, @VikashB I appreciate your orientation on posting errors.

Comment: The error seems to suggest that while fitting you had 17 features, but when trying to predict you only have 3. Check the shape of X and fixt, the number of features should match

Comment: You are correct! But I assumed that after I pipelined  the original X with 17 features by RFECV followed by GridsearchCV the model would be completed and self adjust features. Was I wrong? Should I drop those 14 colums (other features) and CV sole the classifier? This manual intervention seems contraproducent. Is there an automatized way to accomplish that by sklearn implementations? Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an automated way to make it but I created a new pipeline with RandomForestClassfiers taken from the best estimator from previous pipeline, fitted and then predicted. I had to RFE it before tough.

Instead `ppln.fit(X, y.ravel())` the final code was

```
params = search.best_estimator_.get_params()
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(**params)
ppln_new = Pipeline(steps=[('rfe',rfe),('pred',rfc)])
ppln_new.fit(X, y.ravel())
fixt['Predicted'] = ppln_new.predict(fixt)
```